# How to ship data files with a python binary distribution?

Tags: python, packaging, python-wheel, data-files

I'd like to create a bdist for my Python package.
The package contains a `LICENSE` file which is mandatory as part of the distribution.

I added a reference to the `LICENSE` file in my `MANIFEST.IN` file, and indeed after creating an sdist for my package, the `LICENSE` file was there.

However, it seems like when I build a Python wheel for my package (`python setup.py bdist_wheel`), the `LICENSE` file is nowhere to be seen.

I'm familiar with the setup.py's concepts of `package_data` and `data_files` - yet they do not seem to be relevant in my use case:
`package_data` requires the `LICENSE` file to be inside a Python package, but I'm required to have this file on the top level folder of the project, which isn't a Python package.
`data_files` requires me to map the target directory for the file after installation, but instead of having it be relative to the project's packages, it's relative to the python installation - which I find to be very weird, as it might depend on the OS/platform, whether `virtualenv` is used or not, etc.

I understand that at the end of the day, the packages get installed under `site-packages` and there's no room for "top level files" post-installation. Still, I'm looking for a way to have the `LICENSE` file as part of my `wheel`, even if it doesn't get copied later on during installation to any specific location.

Answer (score 0):

You can use relative path to the data files:

```
package_data={"package": ["../LICENSE", …]},
```